# Can we move the success function outside .ajax?

Tags: jquery

In the jquery example , I saw it is usually to define success function inside  $.ajax()
can we move it outside the body.

Comment: You have to explain why you needs?

Comment: @Shakti Singh: no, he doesn't have to. It is pretty trivial - for example when we need to have the same handler for several `$.ajax`, or when the function is already defined somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean something like this:

```
function onSuccess()
{
    $(this).addClass("done");
}

$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body,
  success: onSuccess 
});
```

then yes, you can do that.

Comment: almost +1-ed. please pass `msg`, `msg.d` whatever. otherwise whats the point?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course. You can assign an anonymous function to a variable:

```
var handleSuccess = function(data) {
  alert(data);
};
```

or you can make it a named function:

```
function handleSuccess(data) {
  alert(data);
}
```

For both alternatives you just use the name of the variable/function in the object:

```
$.ajax({
  success: handleSuccess
  ...
});
```

Comment: why it is an error to specify the data like this success: handleSuccess(data)

Comment: @user705414: Because then you will call the function and put the return value in the object, you want to put a reference to the function in the object.

Answer (score 0):

I use dojo more than I do jquery but the idea is the same. As long as the ajax call can reference to this outside function there is no reason why you cannot do that.  You may run into the problem that when this ajax function is called it may no longer be able to get to the success function, depending on how you set things up.  dojo.hitch(context, function) will fix this for you.